# NUnit Assert.AreEqual(object a, object b) false negative?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nunit

I can't understand why NUnit Assert.AreEqual is failing.

```
var dataService = new DataService(db);
dataService.Set("Tests", "circle1", circle);
var circleData = dataService.Get("Tests", "circle1");
Assert.IsNotNull(circleData);
var circleCopy = circleData.Get();
Assert.AreEqual(circle, circleCopy);
```

Using NHibernate (storing serialized data, then deserializing it).  I've inserted a breakpoint and inspected the objects in Local variables window -- they are identical.

Here is the NUnit message:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<TestData.TestClassCircle>. Actual:<TestData.TestClassCircle>.
```

Why would this test be failing when the objects appear to be identical?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What is `CircleData`? Does it override `Equals`? Looks to me like you're cloning it, which means that you've got two separate `CircleData` instances. Unless `CircleData` overrides `Equals`, then it will be performing a reference equality check, which will fail.

Comment: Been bitten by this about 3 times myself.  Now I always remember :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is this `dataService` of yours doing behind the scenes but if it is serializing/deserializing you won't get same object references. `AreEqual` compares object references in memory and not values.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Object doesn't implement Object.Equals correctly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx